# The public object is not editable in the application .NET

Tags: c#, .net, windows

There is a form SampleAdd template and other forms such as frmStaffAdd are made based on it. There is a code of frmStaffAdd.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RM.Model
{
    public partial class frmStaffAdd : SampleAdd
    {
        public frmStaffAdd()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public int id = 0;
    }
}
```

There is a PictureBox from Guna 2 in the window header, which has the public modifier, but it is not editable in other forms such as frmStaffAdd.

1. [The SampleAdd picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z80CZ.png)
2. [The frmStaffAdd picture. And the white square are the place for the picture, but if I could edit it, there would be a black icon like near the header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaxGH.png)

Please help me, what am I doing wrong?

I tried to rebuild the project, rebooted the computer, because I have no other ideas to fix it.

Comment: _"Please help me, what am I doing wrong?"_ - Using inheritance with `Form` classes is rarely a good idea in practice. If you want reusable UI for different forms use composition-of-UserControls instead.

Comment: See: [.NET inherited (WinForms) Form - VS designer issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216940/net-inherited-winforms-form-vs-designer-issue)